# How to determine installed packages that can share text?

Tags: java, android

List packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

I know that I can get all of the installed packages on the device this way. How can I filter so I only get applications that I would be able to share text with?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to present a list of available Apps for sharing text to the user?

Comment: I would like to be able to share using Facebook, Twitter, Email, then any other app that is capable of sharing a text link.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by "sharing a text link".

If you mean `ACTION_SEND` for a MIME type of `text/plain`, use `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager` with such an `Intent`.

If you mean `ACTION_VIEW` for a URL ("text link"), use `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager` with such an `Intent`.

Neither of these return "packages", as "packages" are incapable of "sharing a text link". *Activities* might be capable of "sharing a text link"; `queryIntentActivities()` will report the activities that support your desired `Intent` structure.